# Set Rich Text Value not wokring for values with different kinds of formatting

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm attempting to combine two strings of rich text, while keeping their formatting.

```
function formatCombi() {

    // get the sheet and the page

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

    // get the plaintext value of both cells, and their combined value

  var text1 = sheet.getRange(1,1).getValue();
  var text2 = sheet.getRange(1,2).getValue();
  var text3 = text1 + text2;

  var range = sheet.getRange(1,3);

    // get the rich text value of both cells

  var rtf1 = sheet.getRange(1,1).getRichTextValue();
  var rtf2 = sheet.getRange(1,2).getRichTextValue();

    // get the length of both strings and the combined length

  var length1 = text1.length;
  var length2 = text2.length;
  var length3 = length1 + length2;

    //get the formats of both strings

  var bold1 = rtf1.getTextStyle().isBold();
  var bold2 = rtf2.getTextStyle().isBold();

  var italic1 = rtf1.getTextStyle().isItalic();
  var italic2 = rtf2.getTextStyle().isItalic();

  var under1 = rtf1.getTextStyle().isUnderline();
  var under2 = rtf2.getTextStyle().isUnderline();

  var strike1 = rtf1.getTextStyle().isStrikethrough();
  var strike2 = rtf2.getTextStyle().isStrikethrough();

  var colour1 = rtf1.getTextStyle().getForegroundColor();
  var colour2 = rtf2.getTextStyle().getForegroundColor();


  //create style for each string

  const style1 = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle()
      .setUnderline(under1)
      .setBold(bold1)
      .setItalic(italic1)
      .setForegroundColor(colour1)
      .build();

  const style2 = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle()
    .setUnderline(under2)
     .setBold(bold2)
     .setItalic(italic2)
     .setForegroundColor(colour2)
     .build();

  //set the style for string based on the lengths

  var rtf3 = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
  .setText(text3)
  .setTextStyle(0,length1,style1)
  .setTextStyle(length1,length3,style2)
  .build();


  range.setRichTextValues(rtf3);

}
```

This is the code I have so far, but for some reason it always spits out the same error code:

```
Exception: The parameters (String) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Range.setRichTextValues.
formatCombi @ Code.gs:70
```

Does anyone know why this is? I cant see the point of RichTextBuilder being able to have varied formatting if I can't set it as a value, and the examples of this from the documentation work fine.

Comment: last `build` should be `build()`

Comment: Good spot, but still getting the exact same error

Comment: setRichTextValues expects a 2d array:https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setRichTextValues(RichTextValue)

Comment: @Cooper Ahhhh thank you! I meant to use setRichTextValue, not Values - must have tabbed the wrong one in! You're a lifesaver.

Comment: Sorry I edit the wrong answer for a second but I finally realized I was on the wrong page and corrected it sorry,